# Altair empty plot: The compiled spec uses Vega v3, but current version is 4.2.0

Tags: python-3.x, vega, altair

The code below yields an empty plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [1,2,3],
                   'P [mm]': [90.2,100.4,80.1]})
alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(x='Month',
                                 y='P [mm]')
```

The JavaScript console shows the message:

> The compiled spec uses Vega v3, but current version is 4.2.0.

As far as I'm aware, [Altair in fact doesn't appear to use Vega 4.2.0](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/importing.html), although there seems to be some development in this sense on GitHub. The question is: how can I downgrade Vega to the Altair-compatible v3? Or is that not even what I should be trying to do?

Obs.: Using JupyterLab 0.32.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, column names with non-alphanumeric should be avoided in Altair.

In particular, Vega-Lite allows [field names](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/field.html) to include special syntax based on periods and square brackets in order to access data from hierarchical JSON inputs.

These special characters can be escaped, but there is currently a [bug](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4123) in Vega-Lite regarding such escapes. The easiest way to address this in Altair is to rename your input data so the columns do not contain these special characters. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [1,2,3],
                   'P [mm]': [90.2,100.4,80.1]})

df.rename({'P [mm]': 'P'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='Month',
    y=alt.Y('P', title='P [mm]')
)
```

[image]